# Django 2 systemd/journalctl runserver logs not working as expected

Tags: django, logging, systemd

We recently updated our project from Django 1.7 on Ubuntu 14 to Django 2.0 Ubuntu 18 (i know... pretty big jump).

I don't know if this is by design or a difference between Upstart Vs systemd, or perhap django2 and django 1.7's runserver, but logging is behaving different.

With our old project, I would run server, then check logs:

> sudo python manage.py runserver 0:8888
>   sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/backend.log

These logs would give me a print for every refresh and code change. This includes if I made a python error in a file, the server would restart - fail - and then show me the error.

With the new project:

> sudo python3 manage.py runserver 0:8888
>   sudo journalctl -f -u backend

(I assume journalctl is the correct way I should be viewing these logs)
However now, if I have an error in my python script files, the server reboots but there's no print of this happening. If I fix the error, then the server auto reboots again and prints the error I did have while also showing me the usual "your server is running" text.

I would like to get the log file in journalctl to behave the same as it did before in upstart - where it would print out the current error.

Am I missing something with this set up? Cheers for any information.

Comment: This question is quite confusing. You talk about gunicorn and uwsgi, so why are you using runserver? (And why start it using sudo?)

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry, I only mentioned those as an example of what we've updated. I've removed them to keep the question clearer. We use those in production, but what I'm describing here is our local dev environment. We use "sudo" just on our local vagrant box for ease.

Comment: @DanielRoseman does the question make sense now ?

Comment: Not quite, I still don't see what upstart or uwsgi have to do with anything. If you're starting runserver yourself then they don't come into it at all, surely.

Comment: we use vagrant for our local dev env, and on system start (upstart) we call a script which starts the dev server, so we get logs in /var/log/upstart/name_of_service.log
which works really well, but I can't replicate that in ubuntu18 with systemd